# How do I use Ubuntu Server as file server?

Tags: server, windows, file-sharing

In our company we would like to install Ubuntu server for file sharing, is it possible to use Ubuntu as file server for windows based client Operating systems.

what is the procedure to make Ubuntu file server, and i have installed Ubuntu 12.4 server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**File Servers**

If you have more than one computer on a single network. At some point you will probably need to share files between them. In this section we cover installing and configuring FTP, NFS, and CUPS.

[FTP Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html)

[Network File System (NFS)](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html)

[iSCSI Initiator](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/iscsi-initiator.html)

[CUPS - Print Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/cups.html)

SOURCE -> [File Servers](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/index.html)

**Windows Networking**

Computer networks are often comprised of diverse systems, and while operating a network made up entirely of Ubuntu desktop and server computers would certainly be fun, some network environments must consist of both Ubuntu and Microsoft® Windows® systems working together in harmony. This section of the Ubuntu Server Guide introduces principles and tools used in configuring your Ubuntu Server for sharing network resources with Windows computers.

[Introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/windows-networking-introduction.html)

[Samba File Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html)

[Samba Print Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html)

[Securing a Samba File and Print Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html)

[Samba as a Domain Controller](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/samba-dc.html)

[Samba Active Directory Integration](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html)

SOURCE -> [Windows Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/windows-networking.html)

Answer (score 17):

The important thing to remember is that Desktop and Server are the same underlying OS, with different packages & configuration 
In Windows that isn't true
(tx to @jay-bazuzi)

This is a step-to-step answer.

Install samba

```
sudo apt-get  install  samba samba-common
```

Install some dependencies for Configuration tools

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

Installa samba configuration tool

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Make a new user Jones

```
adduser   Jones
```

Make  a Linux  password for  user  jones

```
passwd pirat9
```

Open samba configuration tool.

[image: samba configuration tool]

Add the folder you want to share and setup the permissions

[image]
[image]

Create a samba user

```
sudo smbpasswd -a  jones
New SMB password
retype New SMB Password
```

You can chose any  directory you want to share by  right click on the  folder directory and open the  **share options**

[image]

Now at this point if your ubuntu server has ip: 192.168.1.10
you can access to your folder with a Linux Machine typing on Nautilus address bar:

```
smb://192.168.1.10/pirat9
```

or on a windows machine with:

```
\\192.168.1.10\pirat9
```

Thanks Linuxman for screen and refs:
http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/

Comment: What is that desktop widget showing the system stats? Looks damn cool.

Comment: It is a Conky script.

Comment: You're sharing pirat9's home folder, and then creating a user "Jones." This makes no sense. You should be creating user "pirat9," and creating an SMB password for him/her. Just look at the link you referenced, which shows your errors - http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/. Luckily I figured it out, but other noobs might not.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is yes, you can set up file sharing with Samba. See

- https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

There's also a beginner-friendly tutorial here http://www.howtogeek.com/74459/how-to-create-samba-windows-shares-in-linux-the-easy-way/. If you search for Samba in the Ubuntu Software Center, you'll find a nice little GUI for this.

Comment: First link is now 404.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you have taken the first step towards a good and stable file server :) I have also managed a Windows server 2003 in the past at the company I was working. In the end we migrated towards SuSE Enterprise.
I would always recommend a Linux server for every job that includes the word server in it.

So now, because you are new Ubuntu, I am wondering if you are new to Linux environments? Also, you haven't mentioned what your file server is suppose to do. If you only want to manage home files (movies, music, etc...) between internal desktops/laptops, then I would reckon a regular Ubuntu installation would be enough.