# Which OS version, i386-driver scanner + server

Tags: installation, drivers, server, scanner

I have some of a problem I must have some help with. Here's the thing:

I have the responsibility to replace Windows XP with Linux on a HP Compaq DX2300. I will use Ubuntu since it is the flavour of Linux I am most familiar with. The computer will have two main missions:

Primary, to make data stored at extra internal harddrive able to access from other computers as a server.

Secondary, to make use of a old scanner, ScanExpress A3 USB 1200 Pro, which driver is only compatible with i386/32-bit-system (have the driver in .deb-package).

Both this have to work. I would preferable use the server edition for 13.10 (only amd64), but will it work with the scanner, in any sort of driver backward-compatibility configuration? Since I will install Ubuntu without access to the network the computer later will operate on, how do I do with the installation? Is it easier to install the desktop version and convert it to server edition? I have installed the desktop version nearly twenty times before but I am new for the server edition, so I have not so much experience with the server edition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rule 1: Use what you know the best**

Since you are more familiar with the Ubuntu desktop, install the desktop. **Second,** you will need some sort of GUI (the desktop) to run the scanning software.

Choose your desktop wisely:

32 bit: Since the scanner driver is 32 bit.

12.04LTS: This version will continue to get security updates for three more years, while the 13.10 will stop getting updates in July 2014. In April, the new LTS version will come out (14.04LTS) which will be supported for 5 years after that date.

First try "Simple Scan" the default scanning software with your scanner. Often it does not need extra drivers. If that does not work, install the deb file and try again.

**I assume the file server will serve files to Windows machines.**

For this you will want to install SAMBA. See [How do I use Ubuntu Server as file server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126850/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-server-as-file-server) for detail on how to set it up. You may have to adjust the configuration file of SAMBA once you hook the computer up to the network it will serve.

Also see the [official SAMBA setup documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) for Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Best