# Access files on Ubuntu Server from Win10

Tags: server, ssh, filesystem, transfer

I have set up an Ubuntu Server with ssh so I can run commands and things like that from my Windows 10 laptop but I would like to be able to transfer files using maybe FileZilla or something similar, preferably with a gui on the Windows side. Its for a minecraft server so file access is pretty important and i want it done easily. I am not super familiar with linux in general so any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can access files from a *file server* by using certain protocols, such as NFS (*Network File System*) or SaMBa (*has a few names actually; including CIFS as is usually used by windows users due to IBM's use of SMB in PC DOS 2.0 early 80s*). Pick a network protocol & configure your systems to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Ubuntu Server as file server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126850/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-server-as-file-server)

Comment: You can install WinSCP in windows. It uses `sftp` which in turn uses `ssh`. If you can `ssh` into the Ubuntu server, you don't need to install anything else in Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: Using WinSCP as suggested by commenter lets me access it through the already set up OpenSSH. Thanks user68186!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Or even better, next time, let the author of the comment to repost it as an answer, instead of posting it on your own.